# Android urlConnection (getting html source) NOSCRIPT

Tags: javascript, android, html, urlconnection, noscript

If I'm trying to get the html source of a website in NetBeans there is no problem. But If I try (with the same code) to get the source with AndroidStudio (through my app) the pages shows up different content with the ending message

```
</script>    <noscript>Activate JavaScript in your Browser.  </noscript></html>
```

I got the source by

```
 URLConnection urlConn = videoInfoUrl.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    outputLine += inputLine;
                }

                bufferReader.close();
                return outputLine;
```

Is there any possible configuration for the urlConnection (or an other way) to get the desktop source?

Comment: `to get the source with AndroidStudio`. No Android Studio has nothing to do with it. Your app tries it. Your app is running on your device. You try to get the page with url connection.

Comment: Well the website acts normal as http url connection does not understand javascript for sure.

Comment: Maybe you coud add a header faking that you understand javascript. But then still if there is javascript sent it will not be executed by http url connection.

Comment: Yes I wrote defined that sentence wrong. Thanks! I don't want to execute the JS - but just see the script (instead of the message)